# ASP.NET Root folder of website in CSS

Tags: asp.net, html, css

So, I thought I'd try my luck on ASP.NET. I didn't get very far before I found my first problem.

I have a folder layout like so:

```
\
->Admin
-->Admin.Aspx

->CSS
-->Style.css

->Images
-->bg.gif

Default.aspx
Default.master
```

Both `admin.aspx` and `default.aspx` use the `default.master` page, which contains the line:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS/Style.css" media="screen" />
```

This works for the `default.aspx` page, because the path is valid, but for the admin page it's not.

Is there any special character, like ~ for home in Linux, to indicate the root path?
I can't use just a slash, because the website maybe under a sub folder when hosted.

Hopefully I've explained myself so you can understand what I need to do :)

I guess it's more an HTML issue than an ASP issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your `<head></head>` tag contains runat="server" (which IIRC it does by default) you can simply specify it as:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="~/CSS/Style.css" media="screen" />
```

Comment: Don't you need runat=server with the ~/ reference?

Comment: I seem to remember having seen that having it on the head tag is sufficient, but since you mention it I'll just try it out...

Comment: Yes having it on head will do the trick:
<head runat="server">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="~/CSS/Style.css" media="screen" />
</head>

yields:

<head><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../CSS/Style.css" media="screen" /></head>

when my page is in a subfolder to the root

Comment: Wow, I didn't know having the head to be "runat=server" makes its child elements behave almost like server controls. Glad I read this answer.

Comment: Sure do :) same if you have <table runat="server"><tr><td></td></tr></table> your <tr> and <td> will get you a complete HtmlTable structure with HtmlTableRow's and HtmlTableCell's