# CSS Reference Issue

Tags: asp.net, css, vb.net, multiple-domains

I was hoping someone may be able to help out with an issue.

I have a site that is accessed through a root domain (originalDomain.com) and the CSS is linked as below.

```
<link href="../../Styles/Css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

This all works fine

However I can also access this site on a different domain. Rather than the absolute root of the domain this one is accessed at newDomain.com/login. This still points to the files at the location of the original domain but because of the /login is unable to locate the CSS file. I assume the ../../ takes it to newdomain.com rather than newdomain.com/login.

Is there an easy way to have a single CSS reference without any back end code changes that will allow the CSS to be successfully referenced at both of the above scenarios.

I hope this makes sense.

Any help is greatly appreicated.

Answer (score 2):

Give absolute paths and not relative ones

```
<link href="/path/to/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Note the first character is a `/` (slash)

Comment: Thanks for that. I did think of this but unfortunately the site is going to be run on multiple servers/domains and therefore the absolute path isn't always going to be available elsewhere.

Comment: I think you mean root path by your example - not absolute

Comment: Then maybe `<link href="http://example.com/path/to/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />`

Answer (score 0):

If your `<head></head>` tag contains runat="server" you can simply specify it as:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="~/CSS/Style.css" media="screen" />
```

[Taken from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1231624/asp-net-root-folder-of-website-in-css/1231696#1231696)